# Ruby on Rails query limit in a range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, limit

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and want to learn the basics of how a database works.

I created a table named `Users` with three columns, `username`, `password`, `email`, and I have three records inside. I made a query:

```
@user = Users.select(:username).limit(2)
```

which works.

Now I want to make a query like:

```
SELECT username FROM Users LIMIT 1,2
```

which means:

> select 2 username column from table Users which starts at index 1

like a normal MySQL query.

I tried

```
@user = Users.select(:username).limit(1,2)
```

but it's not working. I don't actually know what to search for my situation. Tried `limit query with range` or `limit from one to another index query` but neither works.

I think I'm going to need it for printing out products with pages navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use `.offset(1)`

```
@user = Users.select(:username).limit(2).offset(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this one work for me. Let's wait for other suggestion on pages navigation ;)

Comment: I believe dedicated gem for pagination would work great, like ````will_paginate````.

Comment: I'll take a look at your suggestion. Thank you.